# executable .exe file inside container runtime without generating dockerfile

Tags: docker

I wanted to know if its possible to run an executable file ie a .exe file inside container runtime without creating a dockerfile.
I know it can be done using dockerfile using following

```
  FROM ubuntu
    MAINTAINER me@gmail.com
    COPY name.exe /bin/
    CMD ["/bin/name.exe", "input1", "output"]
```

but i dont want to create a dockerfile and execute the .exe inside container. please guide me on this one.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, the reason being *what docker is*. It's a containerization application.

The official docs describe well how is a container different from a stand-alone application

> Fundamentally, a container is nothing but a running process, with some added encapsulation features applied to it in order to keep it isolated from the host and from other containers. One of the most important aspects of container isolation is that each container interacts with its own private filesystem; this filesystem is provided by a Docker image. An image includes everything needed to run an application - the code or binary, runtimes, dependencies, and any other filesystem objects required.

Thus if docker allows you to run an executable file, or any application file (jar, war etc.) without a *docker file*, that fundamentally defies the purpose of using docker. It's pretty much similar to running a virtual machine or running the application directly on your host machine.

Comment: I am new to docker and trying to understand it. In my application i need to run an executable on container each time it is requested. so is it a good idea to generate a dockerfile in the system and then pass it to docker?

Comment: It's indeed possible to create a docker container and start it on the fly using a shell script, get the job done and stop the instance again.

Comment: can you please share any tutorial or example

Comment: You can try something along the lines of this one https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500695/bash-script-to-start-docker-containers